# Changing the display style of a div after executing a header location

Tags: javascript, php, html

So basically I have an SignUp and LogIn form that is popup and activatable by an button to popup. Code Below

**LogIn**

```
<!-- Popup LogIn -->
<div class="bg-modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close">+</div>
        <img src="images/udm_logo.png" height="95px">
        <form action="includes/login.php" method="post">
            <p class="tag-name">Email</p>
            <input type="email" class="login" name="email">
            <p class="tag-name">Password</p>
            <input type="password" class="login" name="password">
            <button id="btnLogin" name="login">LogIn</button>
        </form>
        <button id="btnSignup">SignUp</button>
        <?php  include 'js/errors.php'; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**LogIn CSS**

```
.bg-modal {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: none;
}
```

**LogIn Javascript**

```
const bgmodal = document.querySelector('.bg-modal');
const modalBtn = document.getElementById('login');

modalBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    bgmodal.style.display = 'flex';
    body.classList.toggle('overflow-hidden');
});
```

After clicking the `<button id="btnLogin" name="login">LogIn</button>` it will execute a php code that will check if the user input is correct or not

**LogIn PHP**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["login"])) {

    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $pwd = $_POST["password"];

    require_once 'connection.php';
    require_once 'function.php';

    if (emptyInputLogin($email, $pwd) !== false) {
        header("location: ../index.php?error=emptyinput");
        exit();
    }

    loginUser($connection, $email, $pwd);
    }else {
        header("location: ../index.phpentered");
        exit();
    }
```

This is where my problem starts. After executing the php code it executes the `header` and directs to the page that I defined. But the Popup LogIn disappears after loading the page making it ugly when posting the user error. I would like to know if there's better execution that the Popup Login won't disappear after loading the `header` function.

Comment: The popup disappears b/c you completely refresh the page, so the javascript reloads. If the JS is also generated by php, you can put a "server side variable" in the javascript to control the popup. Otherwise, you will probably have to do something like a query parameter.

Comment: you can append queryString variable in the url and check if it exists show the login popup.

Comment: @DovRine tried applying style changes inside of the php, it didn't apply right after executing the php code

Comment: @WaseelAhmadMufti Can you give a simple example? just for reference

Comment: You can submit the form using AJAX to a php script from javascript - that way you don't need to refresh the page for a submission

Comment: @CSAPawn I'm not sure what you mean about "applying style changes in php". I was talking about modifying javascript from php before the page is sent to the browser.

Comment: @CSAPawn you asked Waseel for an example but you already have this in your code: header("location: ../index.php?error=emptyinput"). The part after the question mark is a queryString. Now that I think about it, you can probably use this exact queryString to automatically show the modal if an error exists.

Comment: @DovRine oh I see what i mean on applying style changes is I tried putting <style> on the php code. 
can you show a simple example on modifying js from php?

Comment: @DovRine oh I get your point, will try that implementation

Comment: @CSAPawn: modifying javascript from php (a stupid contrived example that assumes that your JS is either included in the page or via another included php file): <script>function greet(name){const greeting="<?php echo 'hello'; ?>"; console.log(`${greeting} ${name}`;}</script>

Comment: if(isset($_GET['emptyinput'])){include_once('login.php');}
I hope it will help you.

Comment: Woah Thanks Waseel and DovRine, I found the correct sequence on how to pop up it, big thanks to you two! Sorry for the dumbness, how can I set the answer to this question?

Comment: @CSAPawn If you post an answer yourself of what actually worked for you, then you can also accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is on my error.php which is used to handle the different queryStrings **Code below**.

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
    if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyinput") {
        echo "<p class='error'>Fill in all fields</p>";
}
```

I added a script tag which will handle the different commands to stay `flex` the display style of the popup modal after refreshing the page. **Final Code below**

```
<?php 
if (isset($_GET["error"])) {
    if ($_GET["error"] == "emptyinput") {
        echo "<script>
        const bgmodalphp = document.querySelector('.bg-modal');
        const modalcont_signup_php = document.querySelector('.modal-content-signup');
            if (bgmodalphp){
                bgmodalphp.style.display = 'flex';
                body.classList.toggle('overflow-hidden');
                
            };";
            echo '</script>';
        echo "<p class='error'>Fill in all fields</p>";
```

Thanks to [`@dov-rine`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5277922/dov-rine) and [`@waseel-ahmad-mufti`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8699810/waseel-ahmad-mufti) for the idea.